# nx monorepo with angular application - switch build executor

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nx-monorepo

I am running a nx monorepo with an angular app.

When I am switching the build executor (in the project.json) from @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild to @angular-devkit/build-angular:application follwoing error occours.

> NX   Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>
> ```
> Data path "" must have required property 'browser'.
> ```
>
> Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
> Data path "" must have required property 'browser'.
> at name (C:\git\app\app-ui\node_modules@angular->devkit\architect\src\architect.js:227:19)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

I have deleted the .nx, .angular and the node_modules folder but this doesn't help.
Is there an extra setting anywhere which also must be changed?

**Angular Version: 17**
**nx Version: 17**

PS.: if I am creating a new nx workspace the app works with the " @angular-devkit/build-angular:application" build executor.

Comment: Running `nx report` is more useful info. Looking at [blog post](https://robert-isaac.medium.com/angular-v17-the-application-builder-2482979648bf) and the linked github changes suggest using `"browser": "src/main.ts"` instead of `"main": "src/main.ts"`

Comment: This has solved my problem. Thx